# TSQL QUERY to dump table into a file?

Tags: sql

I want to dump a tale into a text file I am using following command -

```
bcp tablename out myTable.dat -T -C
```

But got error it says incorrect symbol near bcp.

I am not sure why I am getting this.

Comment: see here - http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/creating-csv-files-using-bcp-and-stored-procedures/

Comment: bcp is a command-line program.  You need to specify the database and owner, and can run it from your workstation (might need to provide -S, -U and -P parameters for authentication).  I usually use -c -t to produce tab-delimited files that can be loaded or pasted into Excel easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From @Code Monkey's Link : http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/creating-csv-files-using-bcp-and-stored-procedures/

try this

```
declare @sql varchar(8000)
select @sql = 'bcp [dbname].[dbo].[tablename] out myTable.dat -c -t, -T -S'+ @@servernameexec 
master..xp_cmdshell @sql
```

where *dbname* is the name of your database, and replace *dbo* with the name of the schema if not dbo